# Why does nasm printf char but not string?

Tags: macros, printf, x86-64, nasm

having this:

```
%macro print 2
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov rdi, %1
    mov esi, %2
    call printf
    leave 
    ret
%endmacro

section .data
dat db "string %c", 0xa, 0x0

section .text
extern printf
global main
main:
    print dat, "n"
    mov rax, 60
    syscall
```

It will work fine.

But when I tried to change to this 
(in data section)
`dat db "string %s", 0xa, 0x0`
and (in text section)
`print dat, "something"`
then

```
p.s:18: warning: dword data exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]
p.s:5: ... from macro `print' defined here [-w+number-overflow]
```

If the string is too long (5 and more characters), but if it is only 4 bytes or less, the "only" error: `command terminated`. As seen, the `printf` only accept `dword` (4 bytes) in `rsi` (the second [arbitrary] argument in c style), not greater type, but why? (even if given string of 4 bytes or less, still `command terminated`). How to resolve this?

Comment: `mov esi, "something"` puts the ASCII values in the register, not a pointer to a 0-terminated C string in memory.  `%s` only accepts a pointer; how would it know that a value in register was supposed to be characters by value instead of a pointer?

Comment: I did not know nasm interpret double quotes as literal ascii, but thought to be pointer to array of chars (as is in c). Then I understand the problem. @PeterCordes

Comment: For it to work like C, NASM would have to magically put the string *somewhere* in memory so you could get a pointer to it.  But it's only an assembler, not a compiler; it's not going to magically put stuff in the `.rodata` section for you (or `.data`?  how would it even know whether you wanted read-only or not).  Perhaps that helps understand why it wouldn't even make sense for NASM to work that way.  `section` and `db` directives exist for a reason, and strings aren't first-class objects in assembly, they're something you have to implement.